# How to configure one test in TestNG XML file to start two driver, like Chrome Driver and Android Driver when using QAF

Tags: selenium, testng, appium, qaf

Case Step:

1. Open an web browser to do some step
2. Open Android device with Appium to do some step.

Note: Those two steps should be run in one test of TestNG XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want both driver session be active but want to [switch to another driver by kill current driver session](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/how_can_i_switch_to_another_driver.html) you can set `driver.name` property in code and it will do the needful. **Changing any of following property** in code teardowns existing driver and creates new driver instance:

```
driver.name
driver.additional.capabilities
remote.server
remote.port
```

For example:

```
getBundle().setProperty("driver.name","chromeDriver");
//do the needful


getBundle().setProperty("driver.name","anotherDriver");
//it will teardown chromedriver and create anotherDriver session in next driver call.
//do the needful
```

If you want to have both driver session to be active, [Support for Multiple driver in the same thread/test-case](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/issues/96) has been added since 2.1.11. To change driver within test case you can use `setDriver(String driverName)` method of QAFTestBase. For instance:

```
TestBaseProvider.instance().get().setDriver("chromeDriver");`
```

Refer details in [commit notes](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/commit/05afd005c354dfd985fec0c026e3d9588e319f96).