# Switch back and forth between drivers in qmetry

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, qaf

I have a requirement where I want to switch between multiple drivers to execute tests. For e.g. Launch android app, perform some steps and do the validation in desktop browser. Once done, switch back to android app and continue with rest of the flow.  There can be multiple instances, where I have to switch between multiple drivers

Answer (score 0):

Use `setDriver` method of `QAFTestBase` to swich between drivers.

```
QAFTestBase testBase = getTestBase(); //TestBaseProvider.instance().get()
//switch to another driver
testBase.setDriver("firefoxDriver");
//do the needfull
testBase.setDriver("appiumDriver");
//switch back to mobile driver
```

Refer [answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57775538/861594) and [notes from QAF](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/commit/05afd005c354dfd985fec0c026e3d9588e319f96).

Answer (score 0):

Using QMetry Automation Studio, a user can execute the same feature file on different platforms like Web, MobileWeb, Android using CI/CD. The following blogs have detailed step to set up your QAS project to achieve it:

- [Executing test case by switching multiple drivers](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QAShelp/pages/3017342977/Executing+different+steps+of+same+test+case+on+different+platforms).
- [Executing a test case in multiple browsers in a parallel session](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QAShelp/pages/3017441281/How+to+execute+a+test+cases+on+multiple+browser+in+a+parallel+session).
- [Executing test case on multiple mobile platforms](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QAShelp/pages/3059515402/How+to+execute+a+test+case+on+multiple+mobile+platforms).