# Switch back and forth between drivers (across different environment) in qmetry

Tags: qaf

Switch back and forth between drivers (across different environments) in qmetry. I have a requirement where I want to switch between multiple drivers to execute tests across multiple execution environment. For e.g. Launch android devices in Pcloudy (cloud device management) , perform some steps and do the validation in desktop browser(in browser stack). Once done, switch back to android (in pcloudy) and continue with rest of the flow.
Here the problem is I have update driver capabilities to different environments, as soon as I try updating driver capabilities, previously launched instances gets killed. Is there any work around to maintain both instances and switch back and forth?

Comment: isn't it duplicate of your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614298/switch-back-and-forth-between-drivers-in-qmetry?

Comment: Not a duplicate exactly. Here I have included two different environments (Execution starts with pcloudy environment (mobile) and tries to switch to different environment say browser stack - Chrome). When I try to update driver capabilities, previous driver gets killed. This prevents me to stop switching back and forth.

Comment: Note: In previous case, when i try to switch between different drivers (from chrome to firefox) within same environment (say for example on my desktop ), it works fine. Problem is with switching different drivers across environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can have driver specific resources. Refer [Managing Driver Specific Resource](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html) and [switch-back-and-forth-between-drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614298/switch-back-and-forth-between-drivers-in-qmetry)