# QAF | Switch driver from Web to Mobile or Vice verse is not holding the driver instance parallel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, qaf

Using "switchDriver" to switch between Web and Mobile. When I switch Driver between web to web (Eg: Chrome to Firefox or Vice Versa) the driver instance is holding parallelly, but when I switch Driver between Web and Mobile or Vice Versa it is not holding the driver instance parallelly.

Note: I'm using two different service providers. Web (Browserstack) and Mobile (ExperiTest).

```
@QAFTestStep(description = "I switch driver {drivername}") 
public static void iSwitchDriver(String drivername) {

if (drivername.equals("appiumDriver")) {
            getBundle().setProperty("remote.server","https://experitest/xxxx");
        } else { // chromeRemoteDriver/firefoxRemoteDriver/edgeRemoteDriver
            getBundle().setProperty("remote.server","https://browserstack/xxxx");
        }
        switchDriver(drivername); 
}
```

Some execution logs when switching from Web to Mobile

```
11:53:23.937 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: And I take screenshot
11:53:23.938 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - Executing screenshot parameters: {}
11:53:24.367 [TestNG] DEBUG c.q.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase - Capturing screen shotTest1_Test_EribankScenario_ntqee73ykjnh52.png
11:53:24.367 [TestNG] DEBUG c.q.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase - Info: 
11:53:24.367 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Completed Teststep: And I take screenshot
11:53:24.373 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: Given I switch driver "appiumDriver" with arguments: [appiumDriver]
11:53:24.374 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - Executing quit parameters: {}
11:53:24.474 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - command: quit[ param-1: {}] Result: null
11:53:24.474 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory - UI-driver tear down complete...
11:53:24.474 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: switch to {driverName} with arguments: [appiumDriver]
11:53:24.475 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Completed Teststep: switch to {driverName} with arguments: [appiumDriver]
11:53:24.475 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Completed Teststep: Given I switch driver "appiumDriver" with arguments: [appiumDriver]
11:53:24.489 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: Given I assert "Mobile.login.button" is present with arguments: [Mobile.login.button]
11:53:24.489 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: assert {loc} is present with arguments: [Mobile.login.button]
Driver not configured!... 
Using firefoxDriver as default value. Please configure driver to be used using 'driver.name' property
11:53:24.490 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase - Initializing Driver...browser_str:appiumDriver,base_url:http://www.google.com/,sel_server:https://experitest.com/wd/hub,port:4444
11:53:24.490 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory - Driver: appiumDriver
Oct 03, 2021 11:54:21 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
11:54:21.718 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase - driver init done
11:54:21.719 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - Executing findElements parameters: {"value":"//*[@id='loginButton']","using":"xpath"}
```

Some execution logs from Mobile to Web switching:

```
1:54:31.317 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Completed Teststep: Given I assert "Mobile.login.button" is present with arguments: [Mobile.login.button]
11:54:31.323 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: Given I switch driver "firefoxRemoteDriver" with arguments: [firefoxRemoteDriver]
11:54:31.324 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - Executing quit parameters: {}
11:54:38.295 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - command: quit[ param-1: {}]
11:54:38.296 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory - UI-driver tear down complete...
11:54:38.296 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: switch to {driverName} with arguments: [firefoxRemoteDriver]
11:54:38.296 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Completed Teststep: switch to {driverName} with arguments: [firefoxRemoteDriver]
11:54:38.296 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Completed Teststep: Given I switch driver "firefoxRemoteDriver" with arguments: [firefoxRemoteDriver]
11:54:38.298 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: Given I open "https://demobank1.xxxxx.com/" with arguments: [https://demobank1.xxxxx.com/]
Driver not configured!... 
Using firefoxDriver as default value. Please configure driver to be used using 'driver.name' property
11:54:38.299 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase - Initializing Driver...browser_str:firefoxRemoteDriver,base_url:http://www.google.com/,sel_server:https://browserstack.com/grid1/wd/hub,port:4444
11:54:38.299 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory - Driver: firefoxRemoteDriver
Oct 03, 2021 11:54:42 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
11:54:42.900 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase - driver init done
11:54:42.900 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - Executing maximizeCurrentWindow parameters: {}
11:54:43.222 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.ui.WebDriverCommandLogger - command: maximizeCurrentWindow[ param-1: {}] Result: {x=0, y=0, width=1920, height=1055}
11:54:43.222 [TestNG] INFO  c.q.q.a.step.TestStepListener - Invoking Teststep: get {url} with arguments: [https://demobank1.xxxxx.com/]
```

Appium capabilities:

```
appium.capabilities.accessKey=asdljj.sdasdad.asdasdasd.asd
appium.capabilities.uuid=asdsd23424
appium.capabilities.platformName=android
appium.capabilities.app=cloud:com.xxxx.xxx/.LoginActivity
appium.capabilities.instrumentApp=true
appium.capabilities.appPackage=com.xxx.xxx
appium.capabilities.appActivity=com.xxx.xxx.LoginActivity
appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Browser Capabilities:

```
chrome.additional.capabilities={'name': 'Chrome - Test Run','browserName': 'chrome', 'browserVersion': '89.0' }
```

I have already tried referring below links for solution:
[Switch back and forth between drivers in qmetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614298/switch-back-and-forth-between-drivers-in-qmetry) ,
[How to configure one test in TestNG XML file to start two driver, like Chrome Driver and Android Driver when using QAF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766318/how-to-configure-one-test-in-testng-xml-file-to-start-two-driver-like-chrome-dr/57775538#57775538)

Comment: I think the remote.server which is set when changing the Driver is the culprit. Is QAF offer the option of changing the remote.server and hold the instance within the Testcases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design qaf tear-downs driver instance when observe any driver specific property change. You can try by removing configuration listener(s).

```
    ConfigurationManager.getBundle().clearConfigurationListeners();
```

It may impact on resource load behavior.

To overcome that you can utilize [driver specific resources feature](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html#managing-driver-specific-resource) which allows you to create separate properties file/folder and set as driver resource. In that way when changing driver you don't need to write code for load resources. For example:

```
env.name=qa
env.resources=resources/common;resources/${env.name}
driver.name=androidRemoteDriver

android.resources=resources/android;resources/mobilecloude.properties
ios.resources=resources/ios;resources/mobilecloude.properties
chrome.resources=resources/web;resources/browsercloude.properties
firefox.resources=resources/web;resources/browsercloude.properties
edge.resources=resources/web;resources/browsercloude.properties
```

in above example,

- `resources/web`, `resources/android`, `resources/ios` may contains locator repositories if locators are different for android/ios/desktop-web.
- `resources/${env.name}` may contain resources specific to environment. For example environment specific test data.

Comment: Thankyou for your elaborate answer. Will the above configuration holds the live connection in parallel? Can I continue the scenario where I left in Conn-1 (android) when I move from the second connection (chrome) to the first connection? Eg: android.resources=resources/android;resources/mobilecloude.properties & chrome.resources=resources/web;resources/browsercloude.properties.  Note: I have moved remote.server=https://xxxx.experitest.com/wd/hub into mobilecloude.properties and remote.server=https://browserstack.com/wd/hub to browsercloude.properties. I didn't do clearConfigurationListeners();

Comment: By design qaf tear-downs driver instance when observe any driver specific property change. `clearConfigurationListeners()` will remove property change listener.